# access django channels' consumer class variables from outside

Tags: django, django-channels, consumer

```
class ExampleConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.id = 1
        self.foo = 'bar'
        await self.accept()
```

Is it possible to get all existing instances of ExampleConsumer, filter them by `id` and get `foo` value? Somewhere in a django view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all instance with `gc.get_objects` so:

```
import gc

class ExampleConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.id = 1
        self.foo = 'bar'
        await self.accept()


def get_inc(cls):
    return [obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, cls)]

for i in get_inc(ExampleConsumer):
    print(i.foo)
```